# Calling instance method from another class ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I  am having this runtime error:

```
11843:E, [2015-05-13T11:00:00.467150 #9464] ERROR -- : 2015-05-13T11:00:00-0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:server pid:9464)] Job CronJob (id=5550d0f84d6f747bcb000000) FAILED with **NoMethodError: undefined method `loadData' for AdminController:Class**
```

How I can call the method loadData() from the cronJob class? I test the code using the console and it is working fine if I call from console: **AdminController.new.loadData()**

```
    class AdminController < ApplicationController

    ...

    def setLoadSchedule
        logger.debug "set hour #{params[:admin][:hour]}"
        sethour = params[:admin][:hour]

        Delayed::Job.find(Perseus::Application.config.delayed_job_id).destroy if Perseus::Application.config.delayed_job_id != :nil
    Perseus::Application.config.delayed_job_id = Delayed::Job.enqueue(CronJob.new, cron: '0 ' << sethour << ' * * 1-5')

    hide_action :loadData

    def loadData()
     ...
    end 

    private
    def isAdmin
        if !current_user.admin
        redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    end

  class CronJob < Struct.new("CronJob")

    def perform
      AdminController.new.loadData()
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create controller by yourself, if you really have to invoke some method of controller in lower part of your application, pass instance of current controller as variable.

Example:

```
def index #method of controller AdminController
  CronJob.new(self).perform #so now you are passing controller which inherits from ApplicationController, so loadData method can be invoked on it(if it is public)
end
```

one more thing, in ruby we write `load_data` not `loadData` :)

one more thing#2

if your request is handled by let's say `FooController`, and you want to invoke method from `AdminController` it means you should encapsulate load_data method in some third object (`DataLoader`). Inheriting in `FooController` from `AdminContorller` is not a solution!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, no more loadData(), sorry java world in my head yet. I fixed that already.

Comment: I have made this changes I got another error:   TypeError - can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0x000000086f6078>                                 now I call Delayed::Job.enqueue(CronJob.new(self), cron: '0 ' << sethour << ' * * 1-5') and my cronjob class is like class                                   CronJob < Struct.new("CronJob")
  def initialize(admin)
 @admin = admin
  end

  def perform
    @admin.load_data()
  end
end

Comment: not 100% sure but try this

class CronJob < Struct.new('CronJob', :controller)

  def perform
    controller.load_data
  end
end

Comment: I fixed the issue in a simple way, I moved the load_data() method to a new module load before the admincontroller and the cronjob class and it seen to be working, because it load the job in the database; now I am waiting to the job to run, Thank for you help it was nice to see someone checking my code in a semantic way too. I let you know if my change works fine in the job.